# Can't align image with text

Tags: html, css

I'm having problem aligning an image with text.

```
#content img{
    border: 2px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<div id="content">
    <h1><b>Company News 1</b></h1>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/120x120">
    <span style="">
        A lot of text...
    </span>
</div>
```

The result is this:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is your desired layout?

Comment: see this link somebody was already answered this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6282403/how-to-vertically-align-a-div-next-to-an-image

Comment: see  this also http://www.htmlgoodies.com/tutorials/getting_started/article.php/3479311/So-You-Want-To-Align-Text-Huh.htm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#content img{
  border: 2px solid black;
  float:left;
  margin-right:5px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the text to wrap the image? Try the following instead -

```
#content img {
border: 2px solid black;
float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

check the js fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/5vzBS/

```
#content img
{
     border: 2px solid black;
     vertical-align: middle;
     float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WT9qs/)**

```
#content img {
    border: 2px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left` property

```
#content img{
    border: 2px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width:120px;
    height:120px;
    float:left;
}
```

Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/kJHK7/1/

Answer (score 0):

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fYEE6/)**

Simple and easy. Enjoy

```
#content img {
    border: 2px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float:left;
    margin:0 20px 10px 0;
}
```